# How to get action argument is FromServices or FromBody or another

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an custom action filter for check action parameters before execute the action

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (context.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        throw new Exception("");
    if (context.ActionArguments.Values.Any() && context.ActionArguments.Values.All(v => v.IsAllPropertiesNull()))
        throw new Exception("");

    await next();
}
```

how can I check the `context.ActionArguments.Value` is `[FromBody]` or  `[FromServices]` or `[FromRoute]` and etc...

Comment: check my answer for how to get binding source. But i'm inclined to ask why you would want to do that, I mean what kind of logic do u want to execute in the action filter that depends on knowing the binding source of parameters? I have a feeling that you might be trying too hard to achieve something here, maybe there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the binding source from the `BindingInfo` of each parameter. You get this from the `context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters`. Here is an example.

```
public class CustomActionFilter: IAsyncActionFilter
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        foreach (var parameterDescriptor in context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters)
        {
            var bindingSource = parameterDescriptor.BindingInfo.BindingSource;

            if (bindingSource == BindingSource.Body)
            {
                // bound from body
            }
            else if (bindingSource == BindingSource.Services)
            {
                // from services
            }
            else if (bindingSource == BindingSource.Query)
            {
                // from query string
            }
        }
    }
}
```